# Problem with caption, hyperref and algorithm2e

Tags: floats, hyperref, algorithm2e

I'm trying to mix the `caption`, `hyperref`, and `algorithm2e` packages, but I am having some issues. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[footnotesize,bf,center,figurename=Fig]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[vlined,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\xpretocmd{\algorithm}{\hsize=\linewidth}{}{}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=green!90!black,draft=false,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\renewcommand\figurename{Algorithm}
\captionof{figure}{FOO.\label{alg:foo}}
    \KwIn{}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{figure}[H]
~
\caption{Consistent numbering between figures and algorithms.}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\captionsetup{list=no}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\renewcommand\figurename{Algorithm}
\captionof{figure}{BAR.\label{alg:bar}}
    \KwIn{}
\end{algorithm}
\captionsetup{list=yes}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\renewcommand\figurename{Algorithm}
\captionof{figure}{FOOBAR.\label{alg:foobar}}
    \KwIn{}
\end{algorithm}
Ref: \ref{alg:foobar}.
\end{document}
```

There are two problems:

1. algorithm BAR is in the list of figures, while it is not supposed to because of `captionsetup`.
2. the reference to algorithm FOOBAR links to algorithm FOO, both in the list of figures and in page 3.

Thank you for looking.

Comment: I extended the answer, based on your changed MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you should not know, but `algorithm2e` package has the same mechanism as `figure` and provides a `\listofalgorithms` command, so in this case, there is no need of using `captionof` at all. However, the `BAR` algorithm appears there, contrary to the request. In this case, one has to use the `\TitleOfAlgo{Title}` command to set the caption, but prevent the entry to the `List of algorithms`.

In order to print the algorithm number, the option `titlenumbered` has to be specified in the `\usepackage[...]{algorithm2e}` option list.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[footnotesize,bf,center,figurename=Fig]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[titlenumbered,vlined,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\xpretocmd{\algorithm}{\hsize=\linewidth}{}{}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=green!90!black,draft=false,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms
\newpage

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\caption{FOO.}\label{alg:foo}
    \KwIn{}
\end{algorithm}
\newpage
%\captionsetup{list=no}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\TitleOfAlgo{BAR.}\label{alg:bar}
\KwIn{}
\end{algorithm}
\newpage

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
%\renewcommand\figurename{Algorithm}
\caption{FOOBAR}.\label{alg:foobar}
    \KwIn{}
\end{algorithm}
Ref: \ref{alg:foobar}.
\end{document}
```

**Update**

As the OP explicitly wants to have the algorithms to be listed in the `List of Figures`, the package `\algorithm2e` has to be configured for this usage by adding the `figure` option to the option list of `\usepackage[...]{algorithm2e}`.  The MWE works 'out of the box' then.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[footnotesize,bf,center,figurename=Fig]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[figure,titlenumbered,vlined,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\xpretocmd{\algorithm}{\hsize=\linewidth}{}{}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=green!90!black,draft=false,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\renewcommand\figurename{Algorithm}
\captionof{figure}{FOO.\label{alg:foo}}
    \KwIn{}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{figure}[H]
~
\caption{Consistent numbering between figures and algorithms.}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\captionsetup{list=no}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\renewcommand\figurename{Algorithm}
\captionof{figure}{BAR.\label{alg:bar}}
    \KwIn{}
\end{algorithm}
\captionsetup{list=yes}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
\renewcommand\figurename{Algorithm}
\captionof{figure}{FOOBAR.\label{alg:foobar}}
    \KwIn{}
\end{algorithm}
Ref: \ref{alg:foobar}.
\end{document}
```

The hyperlinks within the LOF are correct also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I want my figures and my algorithms to be printed using the same list, in this case `\listoffigures`, and I want the numbering to be consistant (fig 1, alg 2, fig 3, ...). I might have stripped down my actual document too much to provide the MWE, sorry about that. Anyway, if you think this is possible with your approach, please let me know (I have edited my example). Thanks.

Comment: It might be possible, since the package has a `figure` option. However, in my opinion, you should keep a clear separation between figure and algorithm Toc

Comment: Thank you for your edit, however, while the links are now good, the title of each algorithm is completely messed up (the caption is below the second line, instead of between the first and second line, and centered, instead of flushed to the left). Do you know why that is ? Thank you.

Comment: I believe, that the `algorithm2e` is not setup to work with the `caption` package. Perhaps, there is some setup to be done with `caption`

Comment: @BigDawg: After struggling with `algorithm2e` code, I came to the conclusion, that the first version is definitely easier to use, not because it is a solution by me, but also due to a sense of style that algorithms should not appear in a list of figures, in point of view. Perhaps other users find a better solution. `algorithm2e` seems to screw up the caption settings completely.